# JMeter Testing AJAX Requests

Tags: ajax, jmeter

I have a page which makes ajax calls every 5 seconds and gets new data . After a period of time it gets redirected to another page and stops making ajax requests . Is there any way that JMeter can make those ajax calls after it makes request for each page ?

Comment: Hello, did you find solution to your issue ? Is it below ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate this with a loop controller that would test the break condition and as a child put the http sampler with a 5s timer.